# Дефис "дети-модели"

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Стоит ли ставить дефис с сочетании "дети-модели". По какому правилу действовать?

Answer (score 1):

Дефис ставится: **дети-модели**.

**Правило**

Справочник под редакцией Лопатина (ПАС):

§ 120. Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных **пишутся через дефис:**

б) **сочетания **с однословными приложениями, следующими за определяемым словом,** напр.:** баба-яга, ванька-встанька, город-герой, ковёр-самолёт, лён-долгунец, мать-героиня, пти- ца-носорог, рак-отшельник, рыба-попугай, скатерть-самобранка (устойчивые сочетания); дом-новостройка, журналист-между- народник, писатель-эмигрант, студент-медик, собака-ищейка, солдат-новобранец, садовод-любитель, студент-первокурсник, мать-старуха, девочка-красавица.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!